# How to use filegroup with target|file syntax in please build?

Tags: please.build

I'm using the please build tool and I'm having trouble using the target|file syntax with a filegroup. Specifically, I want to use specific files from the filegroup output in a genrule, but the syntax doesn't seem to work. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
# subdir/BUILD.plz

this = package_name()

a = text_file(
    name = 'a_file',
    content = "aaaaaaaaa",
)

b = text_file(
    name = 'b_file',
    content = "bbbbbbbbb",
)

c = text_file(
    name = 'c_file',
    content = "ccccccccc",
)

filegroup(
    name = this,
    srcs = {
        'A': [a],
        'B': [b],
        'C': [c],
    },
    visibility = ['PUBLIC']
)
```

```
# BUILD.plz

sub = '@//subdir'

a_and_c_concat = genrule(
    name = 'a_and_c_concat',
    srcs = {
        'A': [f'{sub}|A'],
        'C': [f'{sub}|C'],
    },
    outs = ["out"],
    cmd = """
        set -eux
        cat "${SRCS_A}" "${SRCS_C}" > "${OUTS}"
    """,
    visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
)
```

It does the expected behavior if I change the `filegroup` to be a `genrule` and 're-export' `srcs` to `outs` like so:

```
# subdir/BUILD.plz

...

genrule(
    name = this,
    srcs = {
        'A': [a],
        'B': [b],
        'C': [c],
    },
    outs = {
        'A': ['a'],
        'B': ['b'],
        'C': ['c'],
    },
    cmd = """
        set -eux
        cp "${SRCS_A}" "${OUTS_A}"
        cp "${SRCS_B}" "${OUTS_B}"
        cp "${SRCS_C}" "${OUTS_C}"
    """,
    visibility = ['PUBLIC']
)
```

Is there a way to use the `target|file` syntax with filegroup in Please build, or is there another way to achieve the same effect another way?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't implemented at the moment, but I think it's a reasonable thing for Please to do.

Filegroups are just a thin wrapper around `build_rule()`, so they accept all the same arguments, however they don't expose named sources as named outputs. I've created an issue here to track this as a feature request:
https://github.com/thought-machine/please/issues/2701